# Dynamic SQL Query based on values selected in dropdown/radiobutton

Tags: postgresql, grails

I have a controller in a simple grails application which looks like the following:
The where condition here is a static one. I want the filters in where condition(Hourly,Afiiliates)to be dyanamic based on selection made using radio buttons(for timeperiod) and using dropdown (for mv)

```
class Tablev1classController {
    def dataSource
    def listJson = {
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def rows = sql.rows("select date_hour, total_revenue as sales, visits, marketing, organic,single_page_visits,total_units,orders,total_revenue_ly as sales_ly, visits_ly,marketing_ly, organic_ly,total_units_ly,orders_ly,single_page_visits_ly from xyz.mu_ewacs_marketing_vehicle_tylylw where time_period = 'HOURLY' && mv = 'AFFILIATES'")
        sql.close()
        render rows as JSON
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably looking for are named or ordinal parameters. See [Sql javadoc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html), chapters "Avoiding SQL injection" and "Named and named ordinal parameters".

Using ordinal parameters it could be done like this:

```
def rows = sql.rows("select ... from xyz.whatever 
                     where time_period = ? && mv = ?", [timePeriod, mv])
```